# avoid CNContactPickerViewController to show emails

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

I use below code to show contact list in my application:

```
    self.contactPicker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
    self.contactPicker.delegate = self;
    self.contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];

    [viewController presentViewController:self.contactPicker
                                 animated:YES
                               completion:nil
     ];
```

The page shows all contacts including emails . I want to only show numbers (and no emails) is there any options on the `NSPredicate` or `CNContactPickerViewController` itself to show only numbers?

I also used:

```
        self.contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[@"phoneNumber"];
```

But it is not working too.

Answer (score 3):

`displayedPropertyKeys` use this property to control what all fields should be visible.

Swift 5.2 example

```swift
let contactViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()
contactViewController.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

// ... add delegate, present it, etc.
```

A full list of keys can be found at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/contact_keys.

Comment: It should be `self.contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[@"phoneNumbers"];`. It should adhere to the keys declared in the `CNContact`

Comment: I replaced "phonenumber" with "phoneNumbers" but still it show emails too

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show phone numbers for the contact when you select the contact, use the `displayedPropertyKeys` property:

```
self.contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];
```

But if you don't want to even be able to select those contacts who don't have phone numbers, you'd want to set `predicateForEnablingContact`:

```
self.contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.@count > 0", CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];
```

---

I notice that you're using `self.contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact`. But what if the person has multiple phone numbers? Which one are you going to use? Personally, I'd be inclined to not set that property at all, or if you wanted to, perhaps allow the user to drill in and choose the desired phone number if there were multiple phone numbers:

```
self.contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.@count == 1", CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];
```